# Solving for the value of the limit as n approaches infinity

Tags: limits

So, I got a test that contains the question...

[image]

I need to find the value of the limit, the answer I inputted was

[image]

The teacher said I got it wrong, can someone help me find where I messed up?

Comment: Your work is correct if you don't account for the factorial you have tacked on to the end of the limit. What's worse is that factorial is ambiguously placed. Your work is correct for computing

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(  1 - \frac{1}{2^2} \right)\left(  1 - \frac{1}{3^2} \right) \cdots\left(  1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

at least. Or at least I can find no issue with it

Answer (score 0):

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\prod _{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)!=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}+1\right)=\Gamma \left(\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}+1\right)\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$$